# Doing Overriding of function in base class by same name function in the child class of its child class(multiple inheritance)?

Tags: overriding, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following, only program body, syntax not correct:

```
class super
{
  func1();//the method which is to be be overridden
}
class sub1 extends super
{
  func1();
}
class sub2 extends sub1
{
  func1();
}

class Main
{
  main()
}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a multiple inheritance scenario -- just two levels of single inheritance.  Could you say more specifically what your question is?

Comment: I am guessing with the extends keyword, the author may be referring to Java. Like other comments made, that is not multiple inheritance, it  just shows an inheritance hierarchy. Just a note to as well, Java is not design to support multiple class inheritance

Comment: @Fadrian - You are probably right, but isn't `super` also a keyword? Not a good name for your class... I don't think we can answer this question without more information.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is very possible and common use on inheritance. However, for this to work well, some languages require additional keywords (`new` or `virtual`, depending on your intentions)
2. This does not constitute [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). multiple inheritance is when one class is deriving many base classes.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Inheritance is the scenario when one class inherits from multiple classes. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)

Example: class D derives from both class B1 and class B2

```
class D : public B1, public B2 {
};
```

Your example, as itowlson already pointed out, is two levels of single inheritance, which is not same multiple inheritance.